# how to remove faketouch from android feature

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-console

My app does not need faketouch feature to be compatible with an android device, it is a TV app, the feature automatically gets added on release build.

[image]

Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

How can I check whether any library or package in my project cause this feature to be added as required?

Answer (score 0):

Only use uses-feature if you need the feature.  If you don't care if it's there or not, don't include it.  That's what causes these types of bugs.  In general, most apps should have 0 uses features.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however even If I remove those from manifest android.hardware.faketouch feature gets added automatically. that is the reason I'm declaring it as required=false

Comment: That means some library you're using is including it in their manifest.  You need to fix that.

Comment: Any idea how to check which library requires that feature.